# How to turn a weighted Digraph in NetworkX into a Markov Chain

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

I have a directed graph of word association probabilities, but have removed a number of nodes to make the graph connected. As a result, the weights of edges exiting a node no longer add up to 1. Is there a simple way to renormalize them? I.e. iterate over all nodes and then divide every edge weight by the outgoing edge total. That would of course be possible with just a loop, but surely there is a built-in function for that which I just can't find.

In other words, given a networkx digraph object G, I am looking for a method G.function(), so that after its execution, for any node x in G, the sum of edge weights of edges exiting x is equal to 1.

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @yatu Since I'm looking for the existence of a function, I have nothing to reproduce, unfortunately, but I'll try to add clarification on what the function should do.